# I need help removing a border on post content in WordPress using CSS

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I'm sure there is a painfully simple way to resolve this but I haven't been able to figure it out yet:

**What I need**: I need to remove the borders around ALL blog posts on my /blog **page**. These borders are indicated by the red arrows on the picture at this link - https://i.stack.imgur.com/D11Rn.jpg.

**What I've done so far**: I've tried border: none; border: 0px; but it doesn't seem to work for all posts.

I can remove the border for *one* post individually (by copying the CSS path in the inspect element tool) but that's not terribly practical for removing the border on all posts. Whenever I use **.post-content** as the class selector to remove the borders on all posts it does nothing.

**The URL in question**: http://bavarianspaetzle.com/blog/

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated. Again, I'm sure it's quite simple but I haven't found a solution yet (I've tried many things I found on stackoverflow to no effect) and I will be very grateful if someone could provide some guidance.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change style.css ..

line number 621 :

```
 .entry-thumb img{
border:none
}
```

and 
line number 650:

```
 .hentry .post-content, .single .hentry, .page .hentry{
    border:none
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, There are tons of tutorials that help you to cover the CSS concepts.

```
.hentry .post-content, .single .hentry, .page .hentry, 
.entry-thumb img {border:0px;}
```

Put it very bottom of your `style.css` file or add the `!important` in the end if not removed the border.

```
.hentry .post-content, .single .hentry, .page .hentry, 
.entry-thumb img{border:0px !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.hentry .post-content, .single .hentry, .page .hentry {
 border: 4px double transparent !important;
 }

.entry-thumb img {
 border: 4px double transparent !important;
 }
```

in style.css online number 650 or 621

Answer (score 0):

remove this from line 650 and 621

```
border: 4px double #ebebeb;`
```